# how to write an equal method for private enum in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I'm new to Swift and was trying to write a private enum that conforms Equatable. Here is a simplified representation of my code:

```
class Baz {

    /* Other members in class Baz */

    private enum Test: Equatable {
        case Foo
        case Bar
    }

    private func == (lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
        //comparison
    }
}
```

On the line of the "==" method, the compiler is complaining "Operators are only allowed at global scope". And when I change enum Test and "==" method to public then move the "==" out of the class, then the errors go away.

My question is what is the correct way to implement the "==" method for a private enum?

Any help is appreciated.

========

Edit:

Thanks all for helping me out. I didn't specify that my private enum and function above are in a class.. (Code is updated)

Comment: I see two answers that concluded what you have is fine, and they're clearly assuming that you implemented this at the global scope, whereas I'm inferring from your error message that you tried to do this within the definition of another type (e.g. a `class`). Perhaps you can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried in a Playground and it works for me:

```
private enum Test: Equatable {
    case Foo
    case Bar
}

private func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return true
}

class A {
    func aFunc() {
        let test: Test = .Foo
        let test2: Test = .Foo

        if (test == test2) {
            print("Hello world")
        }
    }
}

let a = A()

a.aFunc() // Hello world
```

Can you edit your question with your code? So I can edit my answer to suit your problem.

Comment: Surely you don't want this happening: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57acfee6f01121f27706b037

Answer (score 3):

While perhaps not immediately useful for you, it's worth noting that as of beta 5, in Swift 3 you can make this a `static func` within the type. See the [Xcode 8 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=xcode-8-beta-rn), which says

> Operators can be defined within types or extensions thereof. For example:
>
> ```
>  struct Foo: Equatable {
>      let value: Int
>      static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
>          return lhs.value == rhs.value
>      }
>  }
> ```
>
> Such operators must be declared as `static` (or, within a class, `class final`), and have the same signature as their global counterparts.

This works with `enum` types, too. Thus:

```
private enum Test: Equatable {
    case foo
    case bar

    static func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
        // your test here
    }
}
```

And this even works when this `Test` is implemented within another type.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with what you did:

```
private enum Test: Equatable {
    case Foo
    case Bar
}

private func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    // Put logic here
}

private let test = Test.Foo
private let test2 = Test.Foo

if (test == test2) {
    print("Hello world")
}
```

See [this article for details.](http://www.jessesquires.com/swift-enumerations-and-equatable/)